# Facebook “were here” counter dropped

Tags: facebook

Last month I merged my business Facebook page with the Facebook generated place page, obtaining the likes and the people number of check-ins.

It was all fine until a week ago, when suddenly the "were here" counter dropped from 260~ people to 34 people.

Is it normal? The check-in counter is supposed to be a sort of average statistic, or a simple increasing stacking number for each check-in registered? (I guess the latter as there are pages with tens/hundreds of thousands of check-ins showed.)

Unfortunately, the Facebook help pages aren't that helpful, and I've reported the ticket to developers but I guess the bug tracker it's greatly overlooked.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, when you configure these buttons, they have a hardcoded URL which links the likes to your site.

Perhaps when you merged the sites that URL changed for Facebook, but wasn't updated in your site code.